# How to get hdd drive state (like active/idle,standy) in python 3 without admin rights?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, debian, hard-drive

Is there a way to get the status of a hard drive in debian linux without admin rights in python?

What I have done (in shell, not python):

**1. I installed hdparm via shell:**

```
sudo apt-get install hdparm
```

**2. In the shell I can type now:**

```
sudo /sbin/hdparm -C /dev/disk/by-label/harddrive1
```

**3. The output is:**

```
/dev/disk/by-label/harddrive1:
drive state is:  standby
```

I want to grep the state like "drive state is: standby" or "drive state is: active/idle". With bash and admin rights it is very easy. **But I want to read the device state (standby, active/idle) in python without admin rights.**

Is there a way to do this in python 3 without admin rights? It does not need to be hdparm.

Comment: what admin rights?  I don't see you applying any admin rights to `hdparm`.  did you omit the `sudo`?

Comment: In this case I use `sudo /sbin/hdparm -C /dev/disk/by-label/harddrive1`. Forget it to type before in this example.
If I don't type sudo or have type changed to su before the output will be `/dev/disk/by-label/harddrive1: Permission denied`